# How do I not log a particular type of Exception in Logback?

Tags: exception, logging, configuration, logback

How do I configure Logback to ignore logging on exceptions of a particular type?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do it with a simple `EvaluatorFilter`:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
    <evaluator>
        <expression>java.lang.RuntimeException.class.isInstance(throwable)</expression>
    </evaluator>
    <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
</filter>
```

Please note that you need the following dependency in your `pom.xml` as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Another possible solution is a custom `Filter` implementation:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.IThrowableProxy;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy;
import ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;

public class SampleFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

    private Class<?> exceptionClass;

    public SampleFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(final ILoggingEvent event) {
        final IThrowableProxy throwableProxy = event.getThrowableProxy();
        if (throwableProxy == null) {
            return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }

        if (!(throwableProxy instanceof ThrowableProxy)) {
            return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }

        final ThrowableProxy throwableProxyImpl = 
            (ThrowableProxy) throwableProxy;
        final Throwable throwable = throwableProxyImpl.getThrowable();
        if (exceptionClass.isInstance(throwable)) {
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        }

        return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
    }

    public void setExceptionClassName(final String exceptionClassName) {
        try {
            exceptionClass = Class.forName(exceptionClassName);
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class is unavailable: "
                    + exceptionClassName, e);
        }
    }
}
```

With a proper config:

```
<filter class="hu.palacsint.logbacktest.SampleFilter">
    <exceptionClassName>java.lang.Exception</exceptionClassName>
</filter>
```

In a `TurboFilter` [you get the thrown `Throwable` instance directly](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/TurboFilter.html#decide%28org.slf4j.Marker,%20ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger,%20ch.qos.logback.classic.Level,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Throwable%29), so you can call the [`isInstance`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) method without manually casting the `IThrowableProxy` to `ThrowableProxy`.

[Further documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html)

Comment: Thanks, I have since worked around that particular issue but this is good information for the future.

Comment: Adding the evaluator by itself in Logback XML, `<expression>java.lang.RuntimeException.class.isInstance(throwable)</expression>`, doesn't do anything. The error still gets printed.

Comment: @geneb. Have you added the complete `filter` section inside the proper `appender` element? It's a quite old answer but still works for me with Logback 1.4.6.

Comment: Yes, that was problem -- it wasn't inside the `appender` element. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question is 5 years old, but I'm supplying the solution I found just to keep it up to date.

I found a solution in the offical docs:
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html

For my particular situation, which is a 17 year old web site running plain old servlets (ah, the days), the servlet is now throwing an exception if the user was not logged in.  So here's my code snippets:

**Servlet**

```
  try {
    InvalidLoginException.throwIfBadLogin(webUser);

    // main logic here

  } catch (InvalidLoginException e) {
    throw e;
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    log.error(t);
    throw new UnhandledException(t);
  }
```

**web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>com.mycompany.servlet.exception.InvalidLoginException</exception-type>
    <location>/servlet/Login</location>
</error-page>
```

From the setup above, I didn't want to log this exception as it's not *really* an exception, but rather a break in logic to redirect to login.

So, the start of my **logback.xml** file is this:

```
  <configuration packagingData="true" scan="true" debug="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <evaluator name="InvalidLoginExceptionSuppressor">
      <expression>throwable != null &amp;&amp; throwable instanceof com.mycompany.servlet.exception.InvalidLoginException</expression>
    </evaluator>
```

and further down in the logback.xml file, my appenders:

```
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %ex{full,InvalidLoginExceptionSuppressor}%n</pattern>
      <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
```

Also note, in order to this work, I had to include [janino](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.janino/janino) to handle the expression parsing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an additional example of the response of [@palacsint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368873/984838) that apply when the error is not an exception using [JaninoEventEvaluator](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#JaninoEventEvaluator):

```xml
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
  <evaluator>
    <expression>logger.equals("org.docx4j.fonts.GlyphCheck") &amp;&amp; level == ERROR</expression>
  </evaluator>
  <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
</filter>
```

Comment: If it's a logger you're ignoring you can just disable that logger <logger name="test-please-ignore" level="OFF" />

Comment: What is "GlyphCheck"? Are you referring to an Exception, or a calling class??