# Modifying Logback Messages via TurboFilter

Tags: logback

I want to use a Logback TurboFilter to modify the contents of logged messages. Specifically, I want to use Spring Security to prepend the username of the logged in user to the message (that way, I can use a simple grep on the logs to find log messages referring to a single logged-in user).

It looks like a custom TurboFilter is the way to go, but the documentation is somewhat unclear relating to what I want to do.

Here's a skeleton of what I want to do:

```
public class LoggingTurboFilter extends TurboFilter {

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(Marker marker, Logger logger, Level level,
            String format, Object[] params, Throwable t) {

        final String userId = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

        // get message
        final String output = String.format("[%s] %s", userid, message); // or just use +

        // ?
        return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
    }
}
```

This way, a log statement in the application log will look like this:

```
[smithjohn] entered methodName()
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logback: modify message via filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439555/logback-modify-message-via-filter)

Comment: Thank you. I had seen that one once and couldn't find it again.