# Logback: How to change log level for specific message and logger?

Tags: logging, logback

I'd like change log level from `error` to `warn` for one specific combination of message and logger.

I have tried to filter out these cases and log it again with the new (`warn`) level. Filtering out worked, however the new log did not appear in the console no matter in which part of the code the logger was instantiated and called.

```
class CustomFilter : Filter<ILoggingEvent>() {
    val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SqlExceptionHelper::class.java)

    override fun decide(event: ILoggingEvent): FilterReply {
        val messageMatches = event.message.contains("my message part")
        val loggerMatches = event.loggerName == SqlExceptionHelper::class.java.name
        val levelMatches = event.level == Level.ERROR

        return if (messageMatches && loggerMatches && levelMatches) {
            FilterReply.DENY.also { logger.warn(event.message) }
        } else {
            FilterReply.NEUTRAL
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried also `Turbofilter` in a similar way as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439555/logback-modify-message-via-filter). I was able to see the new log in this case, but all the aruments of `decide` except logger and level were `null`, so I didn't manage to filter the log to be replaced according to the message.

I'm using Logback 1.2.11