# In Java, using the logback framework, is there a way to dynamically configure throttling for a chatty log message

Tags: java, logback

We have a system deployed in the field that has Java services that use the logback logging framework.  Each service has its own logback configuration file.

We're finding a particular log message being issued at WARN level many times per second.  We're really only interested in seeing this message, for example, once/minute, so that we know the issue is occurring; but we don't want to raise the logging level of the class, such that other messages at INFO level are discarded.

Modifying the code is not an option, nor is doing any modifications to the system that would involve restarting the offending service.  However, we can modify the log configuration.

Is there any way in logback, through the XML configuration file, to achieve this behavior?

**Update**
The messages are similar, but not identical; for example:

```
WARN The following ID will be dropped: 12345
WARN The following ID will be dropped: 54321
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the messages are exactly the same you might look at using the Duplicate Message filter.

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#DuplicateMessageFilter

Or you can use an evaluator filter expression:
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#evalutatorFilter

Like so

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
  <evaluator name="loggingTaskEval">
    <expression>
      message.contains("following ID will be dropped") &amp;&amp;
      (timeStamp - event.getStartTime()) >= 20000
    </expression>
  </evaluator>
  <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
</filter>
```

Found that example here: http://logback.qos.ch/demo.html

Comment: I added a comment to clarify the message content - good reference, but it seems like this is not a supported feature for the DuplicateMessageFilter

Comment: Have you looked at using a custom filter? Here's an example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143929/how-do-i-not-log-a-particular-type-of-exception-in-logback

Comment: The situation is occurring on a deployed system which must remain running, so this is more of a question of "can we dial down this live system" than a question of "how should we fix the programming error".  We already addressed the programming issue, but still need to handle this particular customer's issue

Comment: @Tom Why? If logs are not strict concatenated then filter should do

Comment: Also, the JaninoEventEvaluator would be helpful, had we compiled it in :-)

Comment: Right, but you can edit the logback configuration correct? The EvaluatorFilter is pretty powerful.
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#evalutatorFilter

Comment: We can edit the logback config - I definitely think the EvaluatorFilter is the on the right path, I'm reading the page now to see if there's any way to accomplish what we need (we don't want to filter the message entirely, and we need to fuzzy-match).

If you can think of a way to use standard EvaluatorFilter components to do this and update your answer, I'll up-vote and accept