# Spring, Java : Get email for critical errors configuration.

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, email

I am working on a Spring-MVC project for which I am looking to add some email facility for critical backend error.

So for example, if there is a NPE, or some database exceptions while performing CRUD operations, then for those. Not for network errors as they might be because network is lost between that client and server.

The only way I know how to achieve this is to add try-catch blocks and send an email in catch block with stacktrace, but this is not practical as the code-base is big and has a lot of methods.

Kindly let me know what I can do to make this easier and a bit more elegant. Ofcourse I can write the sending email code myself, but how to trigger this method and send the stack-trace to this method is my issue. 
I am posting my config files, if that helps.

root-context.xml :

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <beans:property name="url"
                        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName"/>
        <beans:property name="username" value="dbUser"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value="dbpass"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.journaldev.spring.model"/>

        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <!--   <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</beans:prop>
                   <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>-->
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="loginServiceImpl" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.LoginServiceImpl"/>

    <task:annotation-driven/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <beans:bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <beans:property name="caches">
            <beans:set>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                        p:name="person"/>
           </beans:set>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configuration for Spring-Data-Redis -->
    <beans:bean id="jedisConnFactory"
                class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:usePool="true"/>

    <beans:bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate" p:connectionFactory-ref="jedisConnFactory"/>

    <!-- Jasypt configuration -->
    <beans:bean id="stringEncryptor"  class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor" lazy-init="false">
        <beans:property name="algorithm" value="algo" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="hibernateEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.hibernate4.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor" lazy-init="false">

        <beans:property name="registeredName" value="jasyptHibernateEncryptor" />
        <beans:property name="encryptor" ref="stringEncryptor" />
    </beans:bean>
```

servlet-context.xml :

```
 <security:global-method-security
            secured-annotations="enabled"
            jsr250-annotations="disabled"
            pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor"/>
        <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/"/>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- locale -->
    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:/locale/messages"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- default locale -->
    <beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="de"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Change locale via url. -->
    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="handlerMapping"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <beans:property name="interceptors">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="com.journaldev.spring.service.DoNotTruncateMyUrls"/>

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="52428800"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <!--  52428800 -->


</beans:beans>
```

security-applicationContext.xml :

```
<security:http pattern="/resources/template/demo/clients" security="none"/>

    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
                             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/dashboard"
                             always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/denied"/>
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
                              token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
     <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>-->

        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
        </security:port-mappings>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>

        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionReg" max-sessions="5" expired-url="/sessionExpired"/>
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="sessionReg" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Remember me ends here -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginServiceImpl">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="loginServiceImpl"/>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans>
```

I hope the question is clear. If there is anything you would like to know. Kindly let me know. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: I don't remember the exact name but there are some custom exception handler (`@Advice` ?) in spring-mvc, just take a look at the doc.

Comment: @RC. : Do you mean '@Aspect'. I cannot find Advice as an annotation.

Comment: see https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @RC. : I took the controller based errors, and its working quite good. Thanks a lot. Kindly frame an answer so I can accept it. Specifically containing the ExceptionHandler annotation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC provides mechanisms to have custom exception handlers for controllers.
This works using the [`@ExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) annotation, for example

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = IOException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleIOException(final IOException exception) {
    log.error("Caught some IOException", exception);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

You can put this magic method in a base controller (will be the superclass of all your controllers), in a specific controller or in a ["controller advice"](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html).

See this blog post for more information: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a logging framework to handle logging and reporting of errors and not deal with it yourself in the application code.

Any good logging framework ([Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), ...) will provide you with some sort of SMTP appender. You can configure this appender alongside regular your file/console appenders and set its root level to ERROR to make sure that only errors will be sent via email. You can further filter the errors by implementing a [filter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) and using it for the SMTP appender.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368873/1291150) for an example of implementing filter for ignoring exceptions of specified type.

Here is a sample configuration of SMTP appender in Logback from the documentation:

```xml
<configuration>   
    <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <filter class="com.example.YourExceptionFilter" />

        <smtpHost>ADDRESS-OF-YOUR-SMTP-HOST</smtpHost>
        <to>EMAIL-DESTINATION</to>
        <to>ANOTHER_EMAIL_DESTINATION</to> <!-- additional destinations are possible -->
        <from>SENDER-EMAIL</from>
        <subject>TESTING: %logger{20} - %m</subject>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%date %-5level %logger{35} - %message%n</pattern>
        </layout>       
    </appender>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
    </root>  
</configuration>
```

This has the benefit that it will work universally across your entire application. The solution suggested in comments using Spring MVC's Exception handlers will work only if the error occurs as a result of calling some controller. But you might get an unexpected error which you'll want to be notified of in scheduled jobs and other components.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out. I cannot extend because Java doesn't support Multiple-inheritance, will find an interface based filter. Will comment if I have a doubt.