# Logback filter by regular expression not working

Tags: regex, logback

I am trying to get regex-based filtering to work with logback but fail to do so. Based on the example on the logback website, here's the respective part of my logback config but all log messages seem to be filtered out by it:

```
<appender name="__CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<encoder>
   <pattern>[%-5level|%d{HH:mm:ss}] %logger{15} %msg [%thread] %n</pattern>
</encoder>

 <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
  <evaluator>        
    <matcher>
      <Name>custom</Name>
      <regex>.*foobar.*</regex>
    </matcher>

    <expression>custom.matches(formattedMessage)</expression>
  </evaluator>
  <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
  <OnMatch>NEUTRAL</OnMatch>
</filter>
</appender>
```

When I comment out the filter part, log statements matching the regex are displayed. I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the noise. The runtime-dependency to janino was simply missing in my setup (see [How do I not log a particular type of Exception in Logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143929/how-do-i-not-log-a-particular-type-of-exception-in-logback)).