# Handle non-SSL client bots for https netty server

Tags: kotlin, ssl, https, netty, ktor

I am using KTor https server for my Android app and I have noticed that bots trying to connect to my server fail because of TLS handshake didn't happen.
This is annoying because my log file is filled with these huge dumps by netty for WARN tag with SL4J logger.
Is there a way to handle such clients without causing an error/warning?
I tried using Request Validation plugin in Ktor but it doesnt work.
This is my logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="io.netty" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="io.ktor" level="WARN"/>
</configuration>
```

This is my Request Validation function in Validation.kt in /plugins folder:

```
fun Application.configureValidation() {

    println("Inside application validation")//this is printed at app startup
    install(RequestValidation) {
        validate<String> {bodyText ->
            if (bodyText.contains("mySite")) {
                println("Received request validation text: $bodyText")//this is never printed
                ValidationResult.Valid
            }
            else if (bodyText.contains("myApp")) {
                println("Received request validation text: $bodyText")//this is never printed
                ValidationResult.Valid
            }
            else {
                println("Received request validation text: $bodyText")//this is never printed
                ValidationResult.Invalid("Request Validation failed for bot")
            }

        }

        validate {
            filter { body ->
                body is Any
            }
            validation { body ->
                println("Received request validation 2 text: $body")//this is never printed
                if(body.toString().isNullOrEmpty())
                    ValidationResult.Invalid("Request Validation failed because its empty")
                else
                    ValidationResult.Valid
            }
        }
    }
    println("After application validation")//this is printed at app startup
}
```

None of the received request validation println are printed in the log file.

This is in my Application.kt:

```
fun Application.module() {

    printMyStr("Inside Application")

    configureValidation()
    printMyStr("After validation")

    install(StatusPages) {
        exception<RequestValidationException> { call, cause ->
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, cause.reasons.joinToString())
        }
    }

    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }


    printMyStr("Before socket")

    configureSockets()
    printMyStr("Before routing")

    configureRouting()
    printMyStr("After routing")
}
```

Example of dump message in my log file:

```
29-09-2023 18:39:13.240 [eventLoopGroupProxy-3-1] [WARN ] i.n.h.s.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler - [id: 0x54c76869, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:1234 ! R:/34.756.619.638:9375] TLS handshake failed:
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 0300002f2ae00000000000436f6f6b69653a206d737473686173683d41646d696e697374720d0a0100080003000000
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1225)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda$1$lambda$0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:296)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
30-09-2023 04:06:41.006 [eventLoopGroupProxy-3-1] [WARN ] i.n.h.s.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler - [id: 0xe8b12e42, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:1234 ! R:/432.690.528.47:9264] TLS handshake failed:
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 0100000000cd00010000414e592d5343502020202020202020204543484f534355202020202020202020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000015312e322e3834302e31303030382e332e312e312e312000002e0100ff0030000011312e322e3834302e31303030382e312e3140000011312e322e3834302e31303030382e312e325000003a51000004000040005200001b312e322e3237362e302e373233303031302e332e302e332e362e325500000f4f464649535f44434d544b5f333632
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1225)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda$1$lambda$0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:296)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you need to get an instance of the logger to print the messages to a log file. Your code just prints to a console.

Comment: I am running the JAR file in a shell script in which all output from JAR is printed to log file.

Comment: You may find this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368873/13963150) helpful to filter those stack traces out.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman since it does not work to filter like you suggested I only can change the log level from WARN to ERROR. I posted an answer below with details for your suggested path, please let me know if I missed something

Answer (score 0):

It does not work to filter exception with Janino, as recommended by Aleksei in comments above.
Here is my logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <evaluator name="NotSslRecordExceptionSuppressor">
        <expression>throwable != null &amp;&amp; throwable instanceof io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException</expression>
    </evaluator>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg %ex{full,InvalidLoginExceptionSuppressor}%n</pattern>
            <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="io.netty" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="io.ktor" level="WARN"/>
</configuration>
```

Following is printed in my log file now:

```
16:21:55,761 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:21:55,761 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/mypath/abc.jar!/logback.xml]
16:21:55,848 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@49e202ad - URL [jar:file:/mypath/abc.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
16:21:56,166 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
16:21:56,178 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.EvaluatorAction - Assuming default evaluator class [ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator]
16:21:56,180 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.EvaluatorAction - Adding evaluator named [NotSslRecordExceptionSuppressor] to the object stack
16:21:56,373 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator@1c72da34 - Adding [return] prefix and a semicolon suffix. Expression becomes [return throwable != null && throwable instanceof io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException;]
16:21:56,373 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator@1c72da34 - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#block
16:21:57,300 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.EvaluatorAction - Starting evaluator named [NotSslRecordExceptionSuppressor]
16:21:57,300 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:21:57,338 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
16:21:57,349 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
16:21:57,360 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder@6b0c2d26 - As of version 1.2.0 "immediateFlush" property should be set within the enclosing Appender.
16:21:57,360 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder@6b0c2d26 - Please move "immediateFlush" property into the enclosing appender.
16:21:57,649 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder@6b0c2d26 - Setting the "immediateFlush" property of the enclosing appender to false
16:21:57,650 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to TRACE
16:21:57,650 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
16:21:57,650 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse.jetty] to WARN
16:21:57,651 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [io.netty] to WARN
16:21:57,671 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [io.ktor] to WARN
16:21:57,671 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
16:21:57,671 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@3d3fcdb0 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Since this did not work and printed the follwing still:

```
24-11-2023 16:22:09.749 [eventLoopGroupProxy-3-1] [WARN ] i.n.h.s.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler - [id: 0x25f5cf98, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:1234 ! R:/415.589.36.796:9666] TLS handshake failed: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 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
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1225)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295)
```

So the only solution to my problem seems changing the logger to only print ERROR level messages instead of WARN level in the logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="io.netty" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="io.ktor" level="WARN"/>
</configuration>
```