# Block unknown http client requests to my https server?

Tags: ssl, netty

My https server works just fine with my Android clients, but some random bots are sending http requests to my server and this is resulting netty throwing TLS handshake failure exception and a very big stack trace that is printed in my log file.
Is there a way to not allow http requests to https server?
Alternatively how can I catch the netty exception so that it does not print the stack trace to log by default.
This seems like a problem for everyone creating backend services, how do you deal with this situation?
My https server is created using KTor.

```
23-11-2023 22:51:39.249 [eventLoopGroupProxy-3-1] [WARN ] i.n.h.s.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler - [id: 0x58e8b7a9, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:1234 ! R:/321.567.33.980:18765] TLS handshake failed:
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 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
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1225)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda$1$lambda$0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:296)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: One option is to configure your logging framework to prevent logging the stack traces of the `NotSslRecordException`.

Comment: Can you please share the code to do this? I have tried using request validation but it does not work. See me code in the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77537252/handle-non-ssl-client-bots-for-https-netty-server

Comment: By following this answer ((https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368873/13963150)), you can filter the `NotSslRecordException` type out of the logs entirely.