# Rate limiter for specific client IP?

Tags: kotlin, networking, ktor

The [Rate limiter plugin](https://ktor.io/docs/rate-limit.html) in KTor does not distinguish between client IPs i.e. all clients use the same token bucket.

1. Is there a way to have a unique bucket for each client IP address?
2. The rate limiter only seems to work if the client is accessing a valid page, but does not count any tockens if client is accessing a page that does not exist. I have applied a global rate limiter and not a route specific one so I would expect it should work. (I want this so that someone cannot bring down my server with brute force attack of million requests per minute.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the `requestKey` configuration method to have independent rate limits based on the client's IP address:

```
install(RateLimit) {
    global {
        requestKey {
            call -> call.request.origin.remoteAddress
        }
    }
}
```

2. By default, the global rate limiter considers non-existent routes.

Comment: Thanks Aleksei, actually I found your answer on another post and used the same way you posted above to make it wor. Can you please tell me where can I find the documentation for the requestKey{}? Other than your answer there is no other way of knowing that this existed...

Comment: You can find the documentation here https://ktor.io/docs/rate-limit.html#configure-rate-limiting.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, thanks!

Comment: Can you please help me solve this problem? Seems like an easy and common problem but I cannot find solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538964/block-unknown-http-client-requests-to-my-https-server

Comment: I just want to block http clients from connecting to my https server before the TLS handshake so that the netty warning is not thrown. Only want https clients to connect to my server.